# jQuery mobile popup transparent purple color box issue with Android app

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, jquery-mobile-popup

I am working on one android app using jQuery mobile and phonegap. I have used jQuery mobile popup to show popup in app. Issue is when I opens popup then it is highlighted by transparent purple box which I don't want. How to remove this transparent purple box?

Screenshot link: 
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwIDqcJXVfuAdm96SHc1c0liT1U/edit?usp=docslist_api

HTML for popup:

```
    <div data-role="popup" id="popupCloseRight" class="ui-content" style="max-width:280px">
                        <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">Close</a>
                        <p>Please enter list name.</p>
                    </div>
```

JavaScript to open popup:
$('#popupCloseRight').popup('open');

Comment: Check your css file. and post some html code related to popup.

Comment: Just open your page on browser and inspect it.so you will see which  is your css is going to apply for this pop-up.

Comment: @BornToWin It is working proper in browser on my pc. No transparent purple box is coming in PC browser, but issue is when I open it as android app.

Comment: That's weird. Are there developer tools on the Android to check the CSS properties or plug the phone if you are not using the simulator to a PC to debug?

Comment: @MysticMagic I have posted HTML above and css is unmodified jquery.mobile-1.4.4.css at http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.css

Comment: i'm not even able to get the popup to show in cordova, i think im not using the right jquery version. Here's my [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26398508/3421340)

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem on my android tablet (Android version 4.2.2) but not on my phone (Android version 4.1.2). I found this link which was very helpful:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/7533

I only commented this line in jquery.mobile-1.4.4.js and now it's working:

```
this._ui.container.attr( "tabindex", "0" ).focus();
```